# Child objects missing when web service receives object

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have a RESTful webservice that performs some persistence operations for an object. The object has some child objects contained within a collection. Once the object is received by the webservice, the collection of child objects is empty.

The code that I've written to call the service looks like this:

```
//create a Foo
Foo f = new Foo();
FooAttribute fa = new FooAttribute();
fa.setFooId(f);
Collection<FooAttribute> fAttribColl = new Arraylist<FooAttribute>();
fAttribColl.add(fa);
//Add a collection of attributes
f.setFooAttributeCollection(fAttribColl);

f.setName("fooname");
WebResource resource = new WebResource();
//send f to the service.
Foo fNew = resource.path(URI+"/createFoo")
                   .accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                   .post(Foo.class, f);
```

The persistence webservice looks something like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("my.application.service.path")
public class MyFooService(){

    @Path("/createFoo")
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    public Foo createFoo(Foo f)
    {
        //Inspecting with the debugger shows that 
        //f.getFooAttributeCollection() returns an 
        //empty collection, even though it was populated in the client   code.
        this.getEntityManager().persist(f);
    }
```

If I set a breakpoint on the first line of `createFoo` and inspect `f` in the debugger, I can see that the `fooAttributeCollection` member is empty, even though the other "simple" members (all are of type `String`, in this case) all have the correct value. I'm not sure why the collection objects are empty.

I'm not sure it matters, but the generated code for Foo and FooAttribute looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fooId")
    private Collection<FooAttribute> fooAttributeCollection;

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<FooAttribute> getFooAttributeCollection() {
        return fooAttributeCollection;
    }

    public void setFooAttributeCollection(Collection<FooAttribute> fooAttributeCollection) {
        this.fooAttributeCollection = fooAttributeCollection;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_attribute")
@XmlRootElement   
public class FooAttribute implements Serializable {
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "foo_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Study fooId;

    public Foo getFooId() {
        return this.fooId;
    }
    public void setFooId(Foo f) {
        this.fooId = f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [peeskillet pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29089843/192801), the problem was not in the webservice, but in the datamodel code backing it. the `@XmlTransient` annotation was to blame for the child objects being empty. However, simply remove `@XmlTransient` was not enough, because I then got errors about infinite cycles between the parent and child in the XML. The resolution was the annotate the getter method for the parent object's ID with `@XmlID`, and in the child I annotated the getter on the parent object with `@XmlIDREF`. This way, the child does not contain a full parent object (which contains a child which contains the parent ad infinitum), it simply contains an element with the ID of the parent object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fooId")
    private Collection<FooAttribute> fooAttributeCollection;

    @XmlID
    //If you want to use anything other than a String, you may need
    //to write your own adapter
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyCusomIntegerAdapter.class)
    public Integer getFoodID(){ ... }

    public Collection<FooAttribute> getFooAttributeCollection() {
        return fooAttributeCollection;
    }

    public void setFooAttributeCollection(Collection<FooAttribute> fooAttributeCollection) {
        this.fooAttributeCollection = fooAttributeCollection;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_attribute")
@XmlRootElement   
public class FooAttribute implements Serializable {
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "foo_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Study fooId;

    @XmlIDREF
    public Foo getFooId() {
        return this.fooId;
    }
    public void setFooId(Foo f) {
        this.fooId = f;
    }
}
```

`@XmlInvereseReference` from Moxy is supposed to also be able to resolve this type of problem, but for some reason it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [`@XmlTransient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html).

```
@XmlTransient
public Collection<FooAttribute> getFooAttributeCollection() {
    return fooAttributeCollection;
}
```

It causes the property not to get mapped. You can see just by using the JAXB API to print the `Foo` object before sending it

```
// Foo f = new Foo()
// set the collection like you did in your post
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(f, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

> **Result**:
>   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
>   `<foo/>`

The same is true for marshalling or unmarshalling. So if you tried to send raw xml, the xml elements still wouldn't map when unmarshalling.

Now I'm sure the reason you have this annotation is to avoid circular references. But this is the problem. One option is to just use a DTO for this type. Also I don't use MOXy, but I've seen that is has some features to handle JPA bidirectional relationships, like what you have here.

Comment: The annotation was added by the code generator. It seems like a pretty simple and common situation (at least in the databases I've seen): a parent entity has child entities that refer to it from another table in a 1:m relationship, but the code doesn't seem to handle it very well. I'll have to remove the XmlTransient annotation, as I *need* to be able to serialize the list of sub-entities, but the sub-entities don't really need a reference to the parent, at least not in the Java code. Just the ID field of the parent would be enough.

Comment: Yes it's very common, but remember that JPA and JAXB are two completely unrelated frameworks. They weren't designed with compatibility with one another in mind. You can look at some of the blogs by [Blaise Doughan](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-xmlinversereference-is-now-truly.html). He's the lead at MOXy. MOXy is an extension of JAXB and does add some support for these situations. But like I said, I don't use it, so I couldn't offer any help with integrating it into Jersey. Me personally, I'd just do with a DTO.

Comment: I tried using `@XmlInverseReference` from MOXY, but it didn't seem to work. I was able to resolve this problem using `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF`.

Comment: You should post your results as an answer for others to see :-)